# How to do one-dimensional linear interpolation in TensorFlow efficiently?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I need to do one-dimensional linear interpolation for building my model in TensorFlow. I tried to follow the definition and write a linear interpolation function. But it is computationally intensive and almost unusable in my model. Is there any efficient method to perform one-dimensional interpolation in TensorFlow?

Here is my code for linear interpolation. similar to NumPy.interp().

```
t contains interpolated values and it has shape [64,64]. 
x contains x-coordinates data points and it has shape [91,1]. 
y contains y-coordinates data points and it has shape [91,1]. 
t and x are numpy arraies and y is a tensor. 

def tf_interpolation_v2(t, x, y, left, right):

    # perform one dimensional linear interpolation
    # returns tensor same shape as t
    # t is the interpolated values
    # x is the The x-coordinates of the data points, must be increasing
    # y is the The y-coordinates of the data points, same length as x.
    # left is the Value to return for x < x[0]
    # right is the Value to return for x > x[-1]

    t = np.asarray(t)
    t = t.astype(np.float32)
    x = x.astype(np.float32)
    y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)
    t_return = []
    t_return_row = []

    for row in t:
        for v in row:
            if v < x[0]:     # value smaller than x[0]
                a = left
                t_return_row.append(a)

            elif v > x[-1]:     # value larger than x[-1]
                a = right
                t_return_row.append(a)

            else:       # finding interval where t is in
                nearest_index = 0       # initialize interval index
                for i in range(1, len(x) - 1):
                    if (v >= x[i]) & (v <= x[i+1]):     # if t larger than x[i] but smaller than x[i+1]. i is the index
                        nearest_index = i               # we need
                        break

                k = tf.subtract(tf.gather(y, nearest_index + 1), tf.gather(y, nearest_index))   # calculate slope
                de_x = x[nearest_index + 1] - x[nearest_index]
                k = tf.divide(k, de_x)
                b_sub = tf.multiply(k, x[nearest_index])                # calculate bias
                b = tf.subtract(tf.gather(y, nearest_index), b_sub)
                a = tf.multiply(k, v)
                a = tf.add(a, b)
                t_return_row.append(a)

        t_return.append(t_return_row)
        t_return_row = []

    t_return = tf.convert_to_tensor(t_return)
    t_return = tf.cast(t_return, tf.float32)

    return t_return
```

EDIT:

I say it is unusable, because: TensorFlow will need to calculate gradients for all of these variables in the linear interpolation function, making the network really hard to train. This might be the answer to the question I asked yesterday.

There is a function in TensorFlow doing bilinear interpolation. 
tf.contrib.resampler.resampler()
Wondering is it possible to use this function to do linear interpolation in my circumstance?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but this is a linear interpolation algorithm I use for a TensorFlow model I am currently developing. The inputs to the model are `x` and `y`, which are the x-values and y-values for the functions I am interpolating on, and `n` represents an array of values I want to interpolate. (The input value for `n` can also be a constant.) I have not tried a value for `n` that is more than two dimensions; in my specific cases, `n` is a one-dimensional array at most. All the function parameters are Tensors in this case.

```
def linear_interpolation(x, y, n):
    # Sort x in ascending order
    sorted_indices = tf.argsort(x)
    sorted_x = tf.gather(x, sorted_indices)
    sorted_y = tf.gather(y, sorted_indices)

    # Find the indices of the closest points
    left_indices = tf.searchsorted(sorted_x, n, side='left')
    right_indices = tf.clip_by_value(left_indices + 1, 0, tf.size(x) - 1)

    # Retrieve the closest x values
    left_x = tf.gather(sorted_x, left_indices)
    right_x = tf.gather(sorted_x, right_indices)

    # Retrieve the corresponding y values
    left_y = tf.gather(sorted_y, left_indices)
    right_y = tf.gather(sorted_y, right_indices)

    # Mask for segments where left_x and right_x are not equal
    mask = tf.not_equal(left_x, right_x)

    # Perform linear interpolation only on non-equal segments
    interpolated_y = tf.where(
        mask,
        left_y + (n - left_x) * (right_y - left_y) / (right_x - left_x),
        left_y
    )

    return interpolated_y
```

My function works by first sorting the inputs. It then looks at the indices before and after the ones highlighted at `n`; i.e. it looks for where in `x` and `y` the values of `n` would be located. I then do a standard `m*x + b` calculation to get the y-values of `n`, where `m = (right_y - left_y) / (right_x - left_x)` and `b = left_y`. Note that I also include a `mask` for when `right_x` and `left_x` are equal so I can avoid divide-by-zero errors that create NaNs. For values of `n` when that happens, I just return the value of `n` in `left_y`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Adding this as an answer, because I just registered and cannot comment yet.
Answering to ndhulipala's post
Thanks for the algorithm. I learned a lot from your post. There is one mistake though. You have to substract one from the left indices. The method returns the index that the element would have, if it would be sorted into the list, not the index left of it. You don't really see it for large sets, but with n = 10 its relevant.
`left_indices = tf.searchsorted(sorted_x, n, side='left') - 1`